# Module not found: Can't resolve './containers'

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the error below

```
import { Home, Services, Contact} from "./containers";
```

every time I try to import like this

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './containers' in 'C:\Users\Admin\source\Project\src
```

however if I do the below it works without problem.

```
import  Home from "./containers/Home/index.js";
import  Servicesfrom "./containers/Servicesfrom/index.js";
import  Contactfrom "./containers/Contact/index.js";
```

inside containers there is
Home/index.js, Servicesfrom/index.js and Contact/index.js

Comment: What's in `./containers`? Is there an `index.js` with named exports? Without knowing what's actually there it's impossible to guess other than "there's nothing with anything importable in `./containers`".

Comment: Show the project setup/file architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if there is a "index.js" file in your `containers` folder that exports the other components as so

index.js

```
import  Home from "./containers/Home/index.js";
import  Servicesfrom "./containers/Servicesfrom/index.js";
import  Contactfrom "./containers/Contact/index.js";


export {
Home,Servicesfrom, Contactfrom
}
```